# html5boilerplate and IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, html5boilerplate

I have built a responsive website on an ASP.NET Dotnetnuke installation, using css-media queres and the html5boilerplate web page template.

While the html5boilerplate is supposed to render html5 support for older browsers (IE8), I have found it to be doing the opposite! My site seems to load fine on IE9, chrome, firefox, etc.. but it is littered with javascript errors and the like when loaded in IE8.

I guess my question is fairly simple. Can anyone confirm that I have correctly set up the html5boilerplate on my website? If so, why is IE8 going crazy?

Also, would anyone be willing to inspect my homepage in IE8, and see if they can help point me in the right direction as to where to begin troubleshooting why the site is breaking?

You can view this issue in action at http://www.yandasmusic.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like you modernizr script isn't loading properly. 
Do you have the following linked properly in your `<head>`?

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

When you originally downloaded the bootstrap folder from [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) there should have been a js folder - if you copied the js folder properly into your own website, you should have the following vender folder with the modernizr script, which makes your website more compatible with anything under IE9.

**Update**
I tried finding the following:
    http://www.yandasmusic.com/Portals/_default/Skins/Yandas-Response/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js

But it returned a 404 error - that could be because I am forbidden from accessing those folders, but you should double check and make sure that it works.

Comment: Hi Gersande, thanks for the feedback. I checked, and on some of the pages the spelling was off a bit, and the script was not loading. Thanks for making me check! However, the homepage that I linked above is not one of them. It was loading the modernizer correctly. What does it look like to you now?

Comment: It now shows me that modernizr is loading correctly! Are you still having your IE problems? It might be worth running your site through modern.ie to see what specifically are your problems.

Comment: [Running your site through modern.ie yielded these js issues](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/compat-scan#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yandasmusic.com) - though this definitely isn't a definitive, modern.ie is not that effective...

Comment: As far as I can tell, your modernizr issue is now fixed and I'm no longer getting any errors. Hunting for incompatibilities is now going to require more in-depth IE testing.

Comment: Thanks gersande for you help. Although the pages are producing javascript error pop ups on IE8, the css media queries and such are loading! I'll have to start some different threads to tackle those. Thanks again. Alex